Mannkendall test and Sens Slope Estimator in R
I have time series data for three different stations in different rows in a excel sheet. I want to calculate stationwise p-value, Tau, S using MannKendall test, and sens slope value usinf Senslope Estimator in R. I am new in R, so I am unable to calculate all these. I want to export my result in a single table, where each row will show each station and each coulmn will include all statistics from Mannkendall and Senslope.
Please find my data attached.
I am new in R, so I am unable to calculate all these. I want to export my result in a single table, where each row will show each station and each coulmn will include all statistics from Mannkendall and Senslope.
Here is a small reprex
examp_data <- structure(list(Station = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Year = c(1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 
1997, 1998, 1999, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 1993, 
1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999), SLA = c(-0.02230592654, 
-0.04892816366, -0.01127946408, -0.01103160296, -0.07038624815, 
-0.0425848039, -0.03427932839, -0.02013883767, -0.04695958907, 
0.000702376482, -0.02090233737, -0.09975735848, 0.004325762963, 
-0.04421532553, -0.01189122662, -0.05996677234, -0.0079877587, 
-0.00349428791, -0.1020290964, 0.006990743898, -0.04358859941
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))


